# Create Generic Custom Component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, types

This is react-native question but similar concepts can be applied to react.

I want to create a CustomView in react-native. I am using typescript.

So far, I have:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    borderRadius: 10,
  }
});

type CustomViewProps= {
  width: number,
  height: number,
  marginTop?: string | number,
}

const CustomView = ({ width, height, marginTop }: CustomViewProps) => (
  <View style={[styles.container, { height, width, marginTop }]} />
);
```

This is ok so far because only 3 props are being used: width, height and marginTop.

However, this is not reusable and it can become verbose if I need to add many more props.

So, the question is: How can I make CustomView receive any props as a native component View could receive?

My guess is I should delete CustomViewProps. Then, I should make the props inherit from the same type that the native component View does. However, I am struggling with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating `CustomViewProps`, I assume that you want to add some specific behaviours to your native component above the already written behaviours of that component.

Let's create an example.

I want to create a button with some specific behaviours but i want it to behave, in other cases, like a normal `TouchableOpacity` component. For example, i want to add a "loading" state which will show a loader inside instead of its content.
So the logic is: create your custom props and **merge you custom props with native's default props**

```js
import React, { FC, ReactElement } from 'react'
import { ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity, TouchableOpacityProps, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

type MyProps = {
  loading?: boolean
  children: ReactElement
}

const MyButton: FC<MyProps & TouchableOpacityProps> = (props: MyProps & TouchableOpacityProps) => (
  <TouchableOpacity {...props} disabled={props.disabled || props.loading} style={[styles.button, props.style]}>
    {props.loading ? <ActivityIndicator /> : props.children}
  </TouchableOpacity>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10
  },
})

export default MyButton
```

The `loading` prop will be responsible for both content of the button or is `disabled` prop. The `TouchableOpacity` component will receive every compatible prop (autosuggest will be enabled because you have assigned the `TouchableOpacityProps`). The `styles.button` will behave like default style but will be overwritten if you specify something different in your `style` prop. That's it!

Comment: Your answer is gold. I just applied it to my component and got it. Thanks!